# sorting multidimensional array - array (not object)

Tags: javascript, sorting, functional-programming

I have an array which contains pair arrays. Looks like this:

```
[[Jack],[1]],
[[Larry],[0]],
[[Veronica],[0]],
[[Sam],[1]],
[[Bob],[0]],
[[David],[1]]
```

I need to sort so that they are sorted alphabetically a-z but any person with a value of 1 comes first

After sorting, it should look like this:

```
[[David],[1]]
[[Jack],[1]],
[[Sam],[1]],
[[Bob],[0]],
[[Larry],[0]],
[[Veronica],[0]],
```

I have both of these sort functions but I need to combine them. Putting them one after another messes up the sorting.

```
q.sort(function(a, b){ //sort alphabetically
        if(a[0].toLowerCase() < b[0].toLowerCase()){
            return -1;
        }else if(a[0].toLowerCase() > b[0].toLowerCase()){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    });

q.sort(function(a, b){return b[1] - a[1]}); //sort value 1/0
```

Comment: There is not as much difference between arrays and objects as you think.

Comment: There are a lot of names and a lot of numbers. I was just trying to conserve processing time.

Comment: Don't prematurely optimize your code.  I encourage you to use JSON objects instead.  It will be much clearer, and it will make your sort comparator function easier to write.

Comment: `a[0]` and `b[0]` would be themselves arrays if your arrays are really as you have described them.  Is each value really its own array?  (array of array of arrays)  I assume this is just a mistake as is not quoting the names.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure js sort is stable.  Not that I'm saying it's the best approach, but assuming your two sorts are working correctly independently, running them in sequence as you have should give the correct result.

Comment: @JamesMontagne, it's up to the implementation.

Comment: @JamesMontagne there are more values in there than just two I am simply listing two to make the problem more clear.

Comment: Ty all for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this.

```
b.sort(function(a, b) { 
    if (a[1] == 1 && b[1] == 0) return -1; 
    if (a[1] == 0 && b[1] == 1) return 1; 
    if(a[0].toLowerCase() < b[0].toLowerCase()){
        return -1;
    }else if(a[0].toLowerCase() > b[0].toLowerCase()){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }});
```

Comment: I'm trying to modify it a little... it's not quite coming out right ... not sure why. Gimmie a sec.

Comment: It seemed to work for me, the only difference is my array of arrays wasn't a third level deep of arrays. `x = [["David", 1], ["Jack", 1], ["Sam", [1]], ["Larry", 0], ["Bob", 0], ["Veronica", 0]]`

Answer (score 3):

More elegant solution:

```
q.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b[1] - a[1] || a[0].localeCompare(b[0]);
});
```

Explanation:

1. `b[1] - a[1]`: this is an expression from your second function; if it's `0` (falsy), second part of the expression is evaluated;
2. `a[0].localeCompare(b[0])`: [`localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) works similar to your first function (plus it has support for locales).

Comment: Checking this out... like the compactness

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
b.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a[1] == 1 && b[1] == 1 || a[1] == 0 && b[1] == 0) {
        if (a[0].toLowerCase() < b[0].toLowerCase()) {
            return -1;
        } else if (a[0].toLowerCase() > b[0].toLowerCase()) {
            return 1;
        }
    } else if (a[1] == 1 && b[1] == 0 || a[1] == 0 && b[1] == 1) {
        return a[1] - b[1];
    }
});
```

Comment: You don't need a condition for third `return`.